# Cannot invoke function in my main ViewController from subclass in Swift

Tags: swift, invoke, func

I've created a method call in my main ViewController called processLogin. The actual process is done in another class from GetRemoteData.swift as below

```
public class GetRemoteData {

  class func getValidationFromServer(success: ((svrData: NSData!) -> Void)) {
     .
     .

     ViewController.processLogin()
   }
```

The line which tries to invoke processLogin which is set out as below

```
func processLogin() -> Void {
   .
   .
}
```

swift won't allow me to invoke this method as it complains that there is a 'missing argument for parameter #1 in call'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, and change to this

```
class func processLogin() {

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked as far as invocation but now in processLogin() it doesn't recognise any of my IBOutlets. It says 'ViewController.type does not have a member named loginView'

Comment: It will not have access to those outlets as they are in another class. I suggest you pass the info required to login via the process login methods as arguments. Do you really need that in another class at this stage of development ?

Comment: Yes , only because I wanted to refresh the login view but I did as you suggested which made sense, so thank you.